Candy Machine - Error running command DataTypeMismatch
This was the error that came when I used the Sugar deploy CLI, it used to work  with the same metadata and everything but it doesn't now? Im not sure why, or if anything changed in the metadata structure. All the metadata was succesfully validated, can't seem to pinpoint where it's coming from.
[1/3]  Creating collection NFT for candy machine

Collection mint already deployed.

[2/3]  Creating candy machine

 Error running command (re-run needed): DataTypeMismatch


I'm facing the same issue , please help if you've found the solution, I tried using the metadata available on metaplex as well but it didn't resolve it

I encountered this error and resolved it by deleting the Sugar CLI and re-downloading it.

Run which sugar to locate where the sugar CLI is installed.
Delete the current Sugar CLI:

sudo rm <path-to-sugar>


Re-install with the command below for macOS, Linux, and WSL:

bash <(curl -sSf https://sugar.metaplex.com/install.sh)

For Windows, follow the instructions on the Metaplex Docs

Yes this works for me too.
I realised I previously used cargo to install it.
so I went to cargo bin folder to delete sugar.exe
then do a git pull and reinstall sugar.
And it works!
